# Xamarin Forms MVVM Validating a form with a Busy Indicator

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have developed a Xamarin Forms App using the MVVMHelpers model from James Montenagro.  One of my pages is a dynamically created form built from an XML definition of that form loaded into the app.  The App then creates the necessary layouts and fields.

When it comes time to validate the form my App loops through the various controls created on the page and validates the inputs to against the form definition to make sue the form has been completed correctly.  This all works fine and is triggered by a 'Save' button command.  Problem is it takes a few seconds during which time the app looks unresponsive.

No problem I thought just add

Acr.Userdialogs.Instance.Loading("Validating form, please wait")

before I do my validation to display an activity indicator.  However i have tried this and read about it and of course it doesn't work as my validation is all synchronous in teh Command handler and the UI doesn't get updated.

I next tried moving my validation function into a thread using

await Task.Run(() => ValidateForm());

but this also doesn't work as the thread needs to access the various UI controls in the view and is not allowed to as it didn't create them.  Now I'm stuck.  How can I display a busy indicator while I am looping through the UI elements to validate them - no point in getting all of the 'answers' from teh form elements into a list and validating them separately as it's the looping through the controls which i assume is taking the time...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute your validation on UI Thread asynchronously then try this one:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async() => {
  await ValidateForm();
})
```

Comment: Thanks - been trying to work out how to implement this as I need to be able to check the status also.  So for example my code is 

bool status = false;
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
 status = await ValidateAndSaveForm();
});

if (!status)
{
    UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(Constants.Constants.Messages.Error_FormQuestions, "Error");
}

Obvious issue here is that I'm checking the status before the validation completes as it is on a separate thread...